# Parsing an XML file and creating a list of its contents

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to read an XML file and parse its content, but I'm having trouble extracting parameters from the file.

The XML file I'm trying to parse looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<root>
    <register_map>
        <Register ID="1" Index="0x100000" DataType="0x0007" ObjectType="0x07" Name="Device Type"/>
        <Register ID="2" Index="0x100100" DataType="0x0005" ObjectType="0x07" Name="Error Register"/>
    </register_map>
</root>
```

My code so far looks like this

```
namespace Test_XML
{
    class Program
    {
        struct RegisterEntry
        {
            public UInt32 index;
            public UInt16 dataType;
            public UInt16 objectType;
            public string name;
        };

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("registers.xml");

            var registers = doc.Descendants("register_map");

            foreach (var register in registers)
            {
                // Fill up a list of RegisterEntrys with contents of XML
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

How can I extract the parameters from "registers" and place them in a `RegisterEntry` object?

Comment: Your DataType and ObjectType, thats base8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
var registers = doc.XPathSelectElements("/root/register_map/Register");
```

It will give you collection of `Register`nodes, so you wil be able to access their attributes and populate your `RegisterEntry` object something like:

```
foreach (var register in registers)
{
    var dataType = register.Attribute("DataType").Value;
    //the rest of the code
}
```

Notice `XPathSelectElements` is an extension method in `System.Xml.XPath` namespace. Make sure you've referenced `System.Xml.Linq` assembly in order to use it.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `.Attributes["name"].Value`. I take it you want those values converted to Int as well, so we need an additional `Convert.ToInt(string, base);`

```
var RegisteryEntryList = new List<RegistryEntry>();

foreach (var register in registers)
{
    //create a new RegistryEntry
    var obj = new RegistryEntry();
    //convert your string to an int value and save it
    obj.index = Convert.ToInt32(register.Attributes["Index"].Value.Split('x')[1], 8);
    obj.datatype = Convert.ToInt32(register.Attributes["DataType"].Value.Split('x')[1], 8);

    //... your remaining properties
    RegisteryEntryList.Add(obj);
}
```

Please note: If your Index is binary (base 2) you need to adapt the conversion accordingly. For more information see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k20k614(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Your query will get you all elements with the name `register_map` - you want all `Register` elements.  Change it to this:

```
var registers = doc.Descendants("Registers");
```

Then iterate through them and take the values you need, converting them to the required types.

```
foreach (var register in registers)
{
    var indexHex = (string)register.Attribute("Index");
    var index = Convert.ToUInt32(indexHex, 16);

    var dataTypeHex = (string)register.Attribute("DataType");
    var dataType = Convert.ToUInt16(dataTypeHex, 16);

    var objectTypeHex = (string)register.Attribute("ObjectType");
    var objectType = Convert.ToUInt16(objectTypeHex, 16);

    var name = (string)register.Attribute("Name");

    var entry = new RegisterEntry
    {
        index = index,
        dataType = dataType,
        objectType = objectType,
        name = name,
    };

    // do something with entry
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use xml Linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Globalization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml =
                "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>" +
                "<root>" +
                    "<register_map>" +
                        "<Register ID=\"1\" Index=\"0x100000\" DataType=\"0x0007\" ObjectType=\"0x07\" Name=\"Device Type\"/>" +
                        "<Register ID=\"2\" Index=\"0x100100\" DataType=\"0x0005\" ObjectType=\"0x07\" Name=\"Error Register\"/>" +
                    "</register_map>" +
                "</root>";

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

            var results = doc.Descendants("Register").Select(x => new {
                id = (int)x.Attribute("ID"),
                index = int.Parse(x.Attribute("Index").Value.Substring(2), NumberStyles.HexNumber,  CultureInfo.CurrentCulture),
                dataType = int.Parse(x.Attribute("DataType").Value.Substring(2), NumberStyles.HexNumber, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture),
                objectType = int.Parse(x.Attribute("ObjectType").Value.Substring(2), NumberStyles.HexNumber, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture),
                name = (string)x.Attribute("Name")
            }).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```